# SQL DateTime Inserted Incorrectly From VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Have a table I'm logging information from a .NET program into.

The VB.NET app explicity dictates the format of the DATETIME string like below

```
responsedt = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

I then pass this into an INSERT statement that updates my table, however even though the entire setup of the SQL Server is en-GB (British English) the DateTime has gone in the following format:

```
2019-09-05 19:09:34.823
```

This was done yesterday so actually should be

```
2019-05-09 19:09:34.823
```

The day and month should be switched around, I have tried performing an update on the table post process to get it to update using the following code

```
FORMAT (xa.daterequested, 'yyyy-dd-MM HH:MM:ss.fff', 'en-gb')
```

How while this works in a SELECT statement it doesn't seem to work when I do the UPDATE statement.

It is not ideal to have to update all the records dates after the initial INSERT so a solution to either the .NET side of the issue or the SQL would be appreciated as its pickling my head.

Comment: If you want to use a date, use a date, not a string.  Learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code and set the parameter `Value` using a `Date`.

Comment: @freefaller `yyyy-MM-dd` is not a settings independent format. It needs to be without dashes to be interpreted correctly with any settings.

Comment: @LuisCazares - thanks for the info... it's always worked for me, so I wrongly assumed it was default... have deleted my comment

Comment: It's confusing because the format is ISO compliant, but for some reason is not defined that way in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options to prevent the error from happening again:

1. Keep dates as date/time data types instead of converting them to strings.
2. Use formats that are not language or settings dependent. In SQL Server these would be *YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.msss* OR *YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mss* (notice the T between date and time)

To correct the dates already inserted you could use the format codes in the CONVERT function.

```
UPDATE t SET
    daterequested = STUFF( STUFF( StringDate, 5, 0, SUBSTRING(StringDate,7,2)), 9, 2, '')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY( SELECT CONVERT( varchar(25), '20190905 19:09:34.823', 121)  AS StringDate) AS x;
```